# JQuery Interest rate calculator woes

Tags: jquery

I've come unstuck with a slider calculator, it's basically designed to help the user work out payments on a loan with the percentage interestRate. I had the original working fine after much head scratching, which calculated but I must have fluked it. I need it to calculate an interestRate or 199.9%.

Any help?

```
$(function () {
//First Calculator Slider
$("#slider_low").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 1000,
    min: 500,
    max: 5000,
    step: 500,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#span_amount").html("&#163; " + ui.value);
        $("#hdn_span_amount").val(ui.value);
        total();
    }
});
$("#span_amount").html("&#163; " + $("#slider_low").slider("value"));
$("#hdn_span_amount").val($("#slider_low").slider("value"));
//End First Calculator Slider

//Go by Month
$("#slider_low_secondary").slider({
    range: "min",
    value: 12,
    min: 3,
    max: 36,
    step: 3,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#months").html(ui.value + " Months");
        $("#hdn_span_month").val(ui.value);
        total();
    }
});
$("#months").html($("#slider_low_secondary").slider("value") + " Months");
$("#hdn_span_month").val($("#slider_low_secondary").slider("value"));
//End Go by Month

total();

//Total 
function total() {
    var amountval = $("#hdn_span_amount").val();
    var monthVal = $("#hdn_span_month").val();
    var interestRate = 0.108;
    var setupfee = 69;
    var interest = parseInt(monthVal * amountval * interestRate);

    //$('#interest').html('�' + interest);
    var totel = parseInt(amountval) + parseInt(interest) + parseInt(setupfee);
    totel = parseInt(totel / monthVal);
    $('#total_amount').html("&#163; " + (totel.toFixed(0)));
    $('#hdn_total_amount').val((totel.toFixed(0)));
    }
    //End Total
    });
```

Comment: What indication do you have that it's not working?  We can't debug this for you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are asking how to calculate the interest rate? The formula is

i = n(e<sup>ln(R+1)/n</sup>-1)

where i is the periodic interest rate, n is the number of periods, and R is the effective interest rate. The effective interest rate is:

R = I/L

where I is the total of interest payments and L is the original loan value.

You have already calculated the total amount of interest in the `interest` variable, so the effective interest rate will be

```
interest/amountVal
```

so your monthly interest rate will be

```
var monthlyRate = monthVal * (Math.exp(Math.log(intest/amountval + 1)/monthVal) - 1)
```

multiply by 12 to get APR

===EDIT===

I must apologize, that is not the correct effective interest rate.  Please ignore this answer and see my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

The general formula for the current balance of a loan with interest compounded once per payment period is

L<sub>n</sub> = L<sub>n-1</sub>(1 + R) - P
Where L<sub>n</sub> is the balance after n payments (L<sub>0</sub> is the original loan amount) R is the monthly periodic rate, and P is the monthly payment amount.

After the last payment, the balance will be 0, so if we start there and substitute in the above equation for all of the payments and simplify, the formula comes out as

L<sub>0</sub>(1+R)<sup>n</sup> - P((1+R)<sup>n</sup> - 1)/R = 0

Now if you happen to be a mathematical genius, feel free to solve that for R.  The best I could come up with is

R = P/(P-RL<sub>0</sub>)<sup>1/n</sup>-1

Since RL<sub>0</sub> is the payment to interest in the first installment, it must be less than the payment amount, so if we start with half the payment amount with a step size of 1/4 the payment amount, and iterate, moving the estimate a step closer to the actual and halving the step each time, we should be able to arrive at a reasonable estimate within a dozen or so iterations.

```
function calcInterest(loanAmt, monthlyPayment, nPayments) {
    var ipmt = monthlyPayment/2;
    var newstep = ipmt/2;
    var step = 0;
    var i = 100; //set this to a suitable value to prevent infinite loops
    while (newstep > 0.01 && step != newstep && i > 0) { //decrease 0.01 to increase accuracy
      step = newstep;
      if ((ipmt/loanAmt) > (Math.pow(monthlyPayment/(monthlyPayment-ipmt),(1/nPayments)) - 1)) {
          ipmt += step;
      } else {
          ipmt -= step;
      }
      ipmt = Math.round(ipmt*100)/100;
      newstep = Math.round(step/2*100)/100;
      i--;
    }
    // this returns the APR
    // take off the * 12 if you want the monthly periodic rate
    return((Math.pow(monthlyPayment/(monthlyPayment-ipmt),(1/nPayments)) - 1) * 12); 
}
```

In my test, `calcInterest(1000,197,12);` returned 1.9880787972304255 which is approx 198.81%